# Create standalone application with grails

Tags: grails

I wonder if there is a tool which creates a demoable version of my grails projects. Something which I can distribute on a CD or USB stick which will run on every environment.

Something which

- comes with one shell script to start the app
- searches for a free server port on the system (no error message if 8080 is already in use)
- starts a jetty server
- starts the standard browser with my application

Does anybody know of such a tool?

Comment: Are you assuming you have the needed JVM on the target machine already, or are you looking for a true stand-alone server application?

Comment: a true standalone app would be great, but I guess assuming that a JVM is already available is ok.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the **[standalone plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-standalone/docs/manual.v8/index.html)** it makes it a lot easier to distribute a demo version of your Grails app.

> "The **Standalone plugin** builds a runnable JAR file with an embedded war
> built from your application and an **embedded Tomcat 7 instance**. This
> allows you to build a single archive that can be **run on any computer
> with Java 5 or higher** by running java -jar standalone.jar. This can be
> convenient for demos or even very lightweight installs of low-traffic
> Grails applications."

Full docs for the standalone plugin are [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-standalone/docs/manual.v8/index.html)

To prepare the jar file...

```
grails -Dgrails.env=demo build-standalone our_cool_demo.jar
```

To run the Grails app (the port is specified as a parameter)...

`java -jar /path/to/jar_name.jar cool_demo localhost 9000`

---

**Update:**

There are actually 2 Grails standalone plugins:

1. The ['**standalone**'](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-standalone/docs/manual.v8/index.html) plugin described above which is based on **Tomcat7**
2. The ['**jetty-standalone**'](http://grails.org/plugin/jetty-standalone) plugin which is based on **Jetty** and works in a similar way

There are also some options based on Hudson and the Winstone project but there isn't a Grails plugin. Here are some links with further information: *[Build executable war using grails, maven and jetty](http://krishnadasari.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/build-executable-war-using-grails-maven.html), [Executable WARs with Jetty](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/10/02/executable-wars-with-jetty/) and [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/)*

Comment: there's also another standalone plugin based on jetty which may work. See the updated answer above for more info.

Comment: please see my answer down below, too. Both plugins do not work for me, but are a good starting point.

Comment: I have used both plugins successfully but was also unable to get them working with some projects. I'm guessing it depends on the project complexity, dependencies and plugins used.

Comment: the standalone-plugin just got an update. So all problems should be fixed by now. will give it a try and report back.

Comment: @Chris : hi , i am having a little prob to understand all this stuff , could you please be available to describe a little more to me

Comment: Can someone explain why it's only suited for low-traffic applications?

Answer (score 2):

Best thing that comes to mind is using a Linux distro on a USB stick with grails installed.  You can export the application as a WAR file, then create a script containing `grails prod run-war` to execute on boot.  Finally, you can open up firefox with `firefox localhost:port#/AppName`

The only downside with this option is you need to boot from the stick and that will create a bit of delay time.  However, the advantages are that you only have to worry about supporting one OS, no port scanning on startup and simplicity.

Comment: Hm. Maybe linux bundled with vmware player... But that means iz will be too big for a CD...

Comment: @Ralf - But it might fit on a DVD

Answer (score 1):

The answer proposed by Chris does not work for my, but it provided me a good starting point:
It seems that it isn't too hard to create such a standalone app:

- jetty is a good starting point: just drop the jetty files on a USB stick and deploy your grails app by dropping the .war file in the webapps directory of jetty
- create a small groovy script which searches for two (!) free ports. You'll need the second to stop the server again
- the groovy script can start and stop the server
- compile the script in order to avoid having to install groovy on the target machine

that's it. I guess I'll post more details when I find some more time...