# Can't import the grails plugin standalone:9.0.0.M4

Tags: gradle, grails

I'm struggling to add a dependency to my `build.gradle`

This is the standalone dependency for grails, you can find it [here](https://grails.org/plugin/standalone)

So I added the line `compile "org.grails.plugins:standalone:9.0.0.M4"` in the `dependencies` of the `build.gradle`'s file.

When the project is trying to resolve all the dependencies, I get this error :

```
Could not find org.grails.plugins:standalone:9.0.0.M4.
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/C:/Users/ledev/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/standalone/9.0.0.M4/standalone-9.0.0.M4.pom
  - file:/C:/Users/ledev/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/standalone/9.0.0.M4/standalone-9.0.0.M4.jar
  - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/standalone/9.0.0.M4/standalone-9.0.0.M4.pom
  - https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/standalone/9.0.0.M4/standalone-9.0.0.M4.jar
  - https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/grails/plugins/standalone/9.0.0.M4/standalone-9.0.0.M4.pom
  - https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/grails/plugins/standalone/9.0.0.M4/standalone-9.0.0.M4.jar
```

I tried those topics but nothing was successful :
[Grails Standalone Plugin Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26880811/grails-standalone-plugin-not-found)
[Create standalone application with grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370711/create-standalone-application-with-grails/10375283#10375283)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a build.gradle, you should be on grails 3 or 4, but you try to use a grails 2 plugin. Those plugins are not compatible.

Grails 3 has build in support for standalone JARs.

https://docs.grails.org/3.3.10/guide/single.html#deploymentStandalone